# CSS-only tabs: how to match content to tab?

Tags: html, css

```css
.myradio {
  display: none;
  height: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.myradio:checked+label {
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* Tabbed Styles */

.tabbed {
  width: 80%;
  min-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 68px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: border 250ms ease;
}

.tabbed ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 48px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.tabbed ul * {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.tabbed ul .myradio+label {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  padding: 10px 24px 8px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-right: 46px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #777;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font: 600 13px/20px roboto, "Open Sans", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  transition: all 250ms ease;
}

.tabbed ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed ul .myradio+label:after {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 44px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: all 250ms ease;
}

.tabbed ul .myradio+label:before {
  right: -24px;
  transform: skew(30deg, 0deg);
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 3px 2px 5px, inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.09) -1px 0;
}

.tabbed ul .myradio+label:after {
  left: -24px;
  transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) -3px 2px 5px, inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.09) 1px 0;
}

.tabbed ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #f4f7f9;
  color: #444;
}

.tabbed ul .myradio:checked+label {
  z-index: 3;
}

.tabbed ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}


/* Round Tabs */

.tabbed.round ul .myradio+label {
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
}

.tabbed.round ul .myradio+label:before {
  border-radius: 0 8px 0 0;
}

.tabbed.round ul .myradio+label:after {
  border-radius: 8px 0 0 0;
}


/* Skins */

.tabbed[class*="skin-"] ul .myradio+label {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0 1px;
}

.tabbed.skin-turquoise {
  border-bottom-color: #1abc9c;
}

.tabbed.skin-turquoise ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-turquoise ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-turquoise ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #34d6b6;
}

.tabbed.skin-turquoise ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-turquoise ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-turquoise ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #40e2c2;
}

.tabbed.skin-turquoise ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-turquoise ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-turquoise ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #1abc9c;
}

.tabbed.skin-emerald {
  border-bottom-color: #2ecc71;
}

.tabbed.skin-emerald ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-emerald ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-emerald ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #48e68b;
}

.tabbed.skin-emerald ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-emerald ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-emerald ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #54f297;
}

.tabbed.skin-emerald ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-emerald ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-emerald ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}

.tabbed.skin-peter-river {
  border-bottom-color: #3498db;
}

.tabbed.skin-peter-river ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-peter-river ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-peter-river ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #4eb2f5;
}

.tabbed.skin-peter-river ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-peter-river ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-peter-river ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #5abeff;
}

.tabbed.skin-peter-river ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-peter-river ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-peter-river ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #3498db;
}

.tabbed.skin-amethyst {
  border-bottom-color: #9b59b6;
}

.tabbed.skin-amethyst ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-amethyst ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-amethyst ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #b573d0;
}

.tabbed.skin-amethyst ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-amethyst ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-amethyst ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #c17fdc;
}

.tabbed.skin-amethyst ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-amethyst ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-amethyst ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #9b59b6;
}

.tabbed.skin-wet-asphalt {
  border-bottom-color: #34495e;
}

.tabbed.skin-wet-asphalt ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-wet-asphalt ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-wet-asphalt ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #4e6378;
}

.tabbed.skin-wet-asphalt ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-wet-asphalt ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-wet-asphalt ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #5a6f84;
}

.tabbed.skin-wet-asphalt ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-wet-asphalt ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-wet-asphalt ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #34495e;
}

.tabbed.skin-sun-flower {
  border-bottom-color: #f1c40f;
}

.tabbed.skin-sun-flower ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-sun-flower ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-sun-flower ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #ffde29;
  color: #0a0;
}

.tabbed.skin-sun-flower ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-sun-flower ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-sun-flower ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #ffea35;
}

.tabbed.skin-sun-flower ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-sun-flower ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-sun-flower ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #f1c40f;
  color: #fff;
}

.tabbed.skin-carrot {
  border-bottom-color: #e67e22;
}

.tabbed.skin-carrot ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-carrot ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-carrot ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #ff983c;
}

.tabbed.skin-carrot ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-carrot ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-carrot ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #ffa448;
}

.tabbed.skin-carrot ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-carrot ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-carrot ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #e67e22;
}

.tabbed.skin-alizarin {
  border-bottom-color: #e74c3c;
}

.tabbed.skin-alizarin ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-alizarin ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-alizarin ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #ff6656;
}

.tabbed.skin-alizarin ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-alizarin ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-alizarin ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #ff7262;
}

.tabbed.skin-alizarin ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-alizarin ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-alizarin ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}

.tabbed.skin-graphite {
  border-bottom-color: #454545;
}

.tabbed.skin-graphite ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-graphite ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-graphite ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #5f5f5f;
}

.tabbed.skin-graphite ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-graphite ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-graphite ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #6b6b6b;
}

.tabbed.skin-graphite ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-graphite ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-graphite ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #454545;
}

.tabbed.skin-concrete {
  border-bottom-color: #95a5a6;
}

.tabbed.skin-concrete ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-concrete ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-concrete ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #afbfc0;
}

.tabbed.skin-concrete ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-concrete ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-concrete ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #bbcbcc;
}

.tabbed.skin-concrete ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-concrete ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-concrete ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #95a5a6;
}

.tabbed.skin-green-sea {
  border-bottom-color: #16a085;
}

.tabbed.skin-green-sea ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-green-sea ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-green-sea ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #30ba9f;
}

.tabbed.skin-green-sea ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-green-sea ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-green-sea ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #3cc6ab;
}

.tabbed.skin-green-sea ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-green-sea ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-green-sea ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #16a085;
}

.tabbed.skin-nephritis {
  border-bottom-color: #27ae60;
}

.tabbed.skin-nephritis ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-nephritis ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-nephritis ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #41c87a;
}

.tabbed.skin-nephritis ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-nephritis ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-nephritis ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #4dd486;
}

.tabbed.skin-nephritis ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-nephritis ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-nephritis ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #27ae60;
}

.tabbed.skin-belize-hole {
  border-bottom-color: #2980b9;
}

.tabbed.skin-belize-hole ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-belize-hole ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-belize-hole ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #439ad3;
}

.tabbed.skin-belize-hole ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-belize-hole ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-belize-hole ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #4fa6df;
}

.tabbed.skin-belize-hole ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-belize-hole ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-belize-hole ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #2980b9;
}

.tabbed.skin-wisteria {
  border-bottom-color: #8e44ad;
}

.tabbed.skin-wisteria ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-wisteria ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-wisteria ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #a85ec7;
}

.tabbed.skin-wisteria ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-wisteria ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-wisteria ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #b46ad3;
}

.tabbed.skin-wisteria ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-wisteria ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-wisteria ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #8e44ad;
}

.tabbed.skin-midnight-blue {
  border-bottom-color: #2c3e50;
}

.tabbed.skin-midnight-blue ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-midnight-blue ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-midnight-blue ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #46586a;
}

.tabbed.skin-midnight-blue ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-midnight-blue ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-midnight-blue ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #526476;
}

.tabbed.skin-midnight-blue ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-midnight-blue ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-midnight-blue ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #2c3e50;
}

.tabbed.skin-orange {
  border-bottom-color: #f39c12;
}

.tabbed.skin-orange ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-orange ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-orange ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #ffb62c;
}

.tabbed.skin-orange ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-orange ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-orange ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #ffc238;
}

.tabbed.skin-orange ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-orange ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-orange ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #f39c12;
}

.tabbed.skin-pumpkin {
  border-bottom-color: #d35400;
}

.tabbed.skin-pumpkin ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-pumpkin ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-pumpkin ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #ed6e1a;
}

.tabbed.skin-pumpkin ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-pumpkin ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-pumpkin ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #f97a26;
}

.tabbed.skin-pumpkin ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-pumpkin ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-pumpkin ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #d35400;
}

.tabbed.skin-pomegranate {
  border-bottom-color: #c0392b;
}

.tabbed.skin-pomegranate ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-pomegranate ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-pomegranate ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #da5345;
}

.tabbed.skin-pomegranate ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-pomegranate ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-pomegranate ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #e65f51;
}

.tabbed.skin-pomegranate ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-pomegranate ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-pomegranate ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #c0392b;
}

.tabbed.skin-silver {
  border-bottom-color: #bdc3c7;
}

.tabbed.skin-silver ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-silver ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-silver ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #d7dde1;
  color: #666;
}

.tabbed.skin-silver ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-silver ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-silver ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #e3e9ed;
}

.tabbed.skin-silver ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-silver ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-silver ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #bdc3c7;
  color: #fff;
}

.tabbed.skin-asbestos {
  border-bottom-color: #7f8c8d;
}

.tabbed.skin-asbestos ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-asbestos ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-asbestos ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #99a6a7;
}

.tabbed.skin-asbestos ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-asbestos ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-asbestos ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #a5b2b3;
}

.tabbed.skin-asbestos ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-asbestos ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-asbestos ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #7f8c8d;
}

.tabbed.skin-dodgerblue {
  border-bottom-color: dodgerblue;
}

.tabbed.skin-dodgerblue ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-dodgerblue ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-dodgerblue ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

.tabbed.skin-dodgerblue ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-dodgerblue ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-dodgerblue ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #33ccff;
}

.tabbed.skin-dodgerblue ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-dodgerblue ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-dodgerblue ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

.tabbed.skin-gray-black {
  border-bottom-color: #28343b;
}

.tabbed.skin-gray-black,
.tabbed.skin-gray-black ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-gray-black ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-gray-black ul .myradio+label:after {
  transition: none;
}

.tabbed.skin-gray-black ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-gray-black ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-gray-black ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #68737b;
}

.tabbed.skin-gray-black ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-gray-black ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-gray-black ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #707a83;
}

.tabbed.skin-gray-black ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-gray-black ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-gray-black ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

.tabbed.skin-black-glass {
  border-bottom-color: #0a0809;
}

.tabbed.skin-black-glass,
.tabbed.skin-black-glass ul li,
.tabbed.skin-black-glass ul li:before,
.tabbed.skin-black-glass ul li:after {
  transition: none;
}

.tabbed.skin-black-glass ul li,
.tabbed.skin-black-glass ul li:before,
.tabbed.skin-black-glass ul li:after {
  background-color: #333;
}

.tabbed.skin-black-glass ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-black-glass ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-black-glass ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #444;
}

.tabbed.skin-black-glass ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-black-glass ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-black-glass ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}
```

```html
<h2>Amazing Tabs</h2>
<div class="tabbed round">
  <ul>
    <form action="#">
      <input name="myradio" type="radio" id="radio1" class="myradio" checked />
      <label for="radio1">Tab 1</label>
      <input name="myradio" type="radio" id="radio2" class="myradio" />
      <label for="radio2">Tab 2</label>
    </form>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I'm trying to add content to different tabs in this code. I have little experience with frontend development, but I have tried for some time now with little success.

I need to mention that I need to use this code to send some in Email Report with Thunderbird client, that's why I am not allowed to use any JavaScript because the email client will not run it, so I need to stick to HTML and CSS only.

code link: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1LyUfU8u_fcIrF9xqAOT_mVPjnO0KKWSOqRH6PVBlrqQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You must post code to the question. Break it down to the most minimal example you can. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: make a snippet here and post your code.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eu81273/812ehkyf/

Comment: @LaljiTadhani post that as an answer. That's real nice.

Comment: Hy there! I've put a link to the sourcecode. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.myradio {
  display: none;
  height: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.border{
  height: 4px;
  background: black;
}

.tabbed section{
  display:none;
}

.myradio:checked+label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

input:nth-of-type(1):checked~section:nth-of-type(1) {
  display:block;
}

input:nth-of-type(2):checked~section:nth-of-type(2) {
  display:block;
}


/* Tabbed Styles */

.tabbed {
  width: 80%;
  min-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 68px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: border 250ms ease;
}

.tabbed ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 48px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.tabbed ul * {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.tabbed form{
  width: 120%;
  padding: 0 40px;
}

.tabbed ul .myradio+label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 24px 8px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-left: 36px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #777;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font: 600 13px/20px roboto, "Open Sans", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  transition: all 250ms ease;
}

.tabbed ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed ul .myradio+label:after {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 44px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: all 250ms ease;
}

.tabbed ul .myradio+label:before {
  right: -24px;
  transform: skew(30deg, 0deg);
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 3px 2px 5px, inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.09) -1px 0;
}

.tabbed ul .myradio+label:after {
  left: -24px;
  transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) -3px 2px 5px, inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.09) 1px 0;
}

.tabbed ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #f4f7f9;
  color: #444;
}

.tabbed ul .myradio:checked+label {
  z-index: 3;
}

.tabbed ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}


/* Round Tabs */

.tabbed.round ul .myradio+label {
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
}

.tabbed.round ul .myradio+label:before {
  border-radius: 0 8px 0 0;
}

.tabbed.round ul .myradio+label:after {
  border-radius: 8px 0 0 0;
}


/* Skins */

.tabbed[class*="skin-"] ul .myradio+label {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0 1px;
}

.tabbed.skin-turquoise {
  border-bottom-color: #1abc9c;
}

.tabbed.skin-turquoise ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-turquoise ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-turquoise ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #34d6b6;
}

.tabbed.skin-turquoise ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-turquoise ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-turquoise ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #40e2c2;
}

.tabbed.skin-turquoise ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-turquoise ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-turquoise ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #1abc9c;
}

.tabbed.skin-emerald {
  border-bottom-color: #2ecc71;
}

.tabbed.skin-emerald ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-emerald ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-emerald ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #48e68b;
}

.tabbed.skin-emerald ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-emerald ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-emerald ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #54f297;
}

.tabbed.skin-emerald ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-emerald ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-emerald ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}

.tabbed.skin-peter-river {
  border-bottom-color: #3498db;
}

.tabbed.skin-peter-river ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-peter-river ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-peter-river ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #4eb2f5;
}

.tabbed.skin-peter-river ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-peter-river ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-peter-river ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #5abeff;
}

.tabbed.skin-peter-river ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-peter-river ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-peter-river ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #3498db;
}

.tabbed.skin-amethyst {
  border-bottom-color: #9b59b6;
}

.tabbed.skin-amethyst ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-amethyst ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-amethyst ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #b573d0;
}

.tabbed.skin-amethyst ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-amethyst ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-amethyst ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #c17fdc;
}

.tabbed.skin-amethyst ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-amethyst ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-amethyst ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #9b59b6;
}

.tabbed.skin-wet-asphalt {
  border-bottom-color: #34495e;
}

.tabbed.skin-wet-asphalt ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-wet-asphalt ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-wet-asphalt ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #4e6378;
}

.tabbed.skin-wet-asphalt ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-wet-asphalt ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-wet-asphalt ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #5a6f84;
}

.tabbed.skin-wet-asphalt ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-wet-asphalt ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-wet-asphalt ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #34495e;
}

.tabbed.skin-sun-flower {
  border-bottom-color: #f1c40f;
}

.tabbed.skin-sun-flower ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-sun-flower ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-sun-flower ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #ffde29;
  color: #0a0;
}

.tabbed.skin-sun-flower ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-sun-flower ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-sun-flower ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #ffea35;
}

.tabbed.skin-sun-flower ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-sun-flower ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-sun-flower ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #f1c40f;
  color: #fff;
}

.tabbed.skin-carrot {
  border-bottom-color: #e67e22;
}

.tabbed.skin-carrot ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-carrot ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-carrot ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #ff983c;
}

.tabbed.skin-carrot ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-carrot ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-carrot ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #ffa448;
}

.tabbed.skin-carrot ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-carrot ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-carrot ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #e67e22;
}

.tabbed.skin-alizarin {
  border-bottom-color: #e74c3c;
}

.tabbed.skin-alizarin ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-alizarin ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-alizarin ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #ff6656;
}

.tabbed.skin-alizarin ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-alizarin ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-alizarin ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #ff7262;
}

.tabbed.skin-alizarin ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-alizarin ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-alizarin ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}

.tabbed.skin-graphite {
  border-bottom-color: #454545;
}

.tabbed.skin-graphite ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-graphite ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-graphite ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #5f5f5f;
}

.tabbed.skin-graphite ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-graphite ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-graphite ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #6b6b6b;
}

.tabbed.skin-graphite ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-graphite ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-graphite ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #454545;
}

.tabbed.skin-concrete {
  border-bottom-color: #95a5a6;
}

.tabbed.skin-concrete ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-concrete ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-concrete ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #afbfc0;
}

.tabbed.skin-concrete ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-concrete ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-concrete ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #bbcbcc;
}

.tabbed.skin-concrete ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-concrete ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-concrete ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #95a5a6;
}

.tabbed.skin-green-sea {
  border-bottom-color: #16a085;
}

.tabbed.skin-green-sea ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-green-sea ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-green-sea ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #30ba9f;
}

.tabbed.skin-green-sea ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-green-sea ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-green-sea ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #3cc6ab;
}

.tabbed.skin-green-sea ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-green-sea ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-green-sea ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #16a085;
}

.tabbed.skin-nephritis {
  border-bottom-color: #27ae60;
}

.tabbed.skin-nephritis ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-nephritis ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-nephritis ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #41c87a;
}

.tabbed.skin-nephritis ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-nephritis ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-nephritis ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #4dd486;
}

.tabbed.skin-nephritis ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-nephritis ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-nephritis ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #27ae60;
}

.tabbed.skin-belize-hole {
  border-bottom-color: #2980b9;
}

.tabbed.skin-belize-hole ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-belize-hole ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-belize-hole ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #439ad3;
}

.tabbed.skin-belize-hole ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-belize-hole ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-belize-hole ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #4fa6df;
}

.tabbed.skin-belize-hole ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-belize-hole ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-belize-hole ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #2980b9;
}

.tabbed.skin-wisteria {
  border-bottom-color: #8e44ad;
}

.tabbed.skin-wisteria ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-wisteria ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-wisteria ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #a85ec7;
}

.tabbed.skin-wisteria ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-wisteria ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-wisteria ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #b46ad3;
}

.tabbed.skin-wisteria ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-wisteria ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-wisteria ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #8e44ad;
}

.tabbed.skin-midnight-blue {
  border-bottom-color: #2c3e50;
}

.tabbed.skin-midnight-blue ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-midnight-blue ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-midnight-blue ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #46586a;
}

.tabbed.skin-midnight-blue ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-midnight-blue ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-midnight-blue ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #526476;
}

.tabbed.skin-midnight-blue ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-midnight-blue ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-midnight-blue ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #2c3e50;
}

.tabbed.skin-orange {
  border-bottom-color: #f39c12;
}

.tabbed.skin-orange ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-orange ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-orange ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #ffb62c;
}

.tabbed.skin-orange ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-orange ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-orange ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #ffc238;
}

.tabbed.skin-orange ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-orange ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-orange ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #f39c12;
}

.tabbed.skin-pumpkin {
  border-bottom-color: #d35400;
}

.tabbed.skin-pumpkin ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-pumpkin ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-pumpkin ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #ed6e1a;
}

.tabbed.skin-pumpkin ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-pumpkin ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-pumpkin ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #f97a26;
}

.tabbed.skin-pumpkin ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-pumpkin ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-pumpkin ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #d35400;
}

.tabbed.skin-pomegranate {
  border-bottom-color: #c0392b;
}

.tabbed.skin-pomegranate ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-pomegranate ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-pomegranate ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #da5345;
}

.tabbed.skin-pomegranate ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-pomegranate ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-pomegranate ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #e65f51;
}

.tabbed.skin-pomegranate ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-pomegranate ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-pomegranate ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #c0392b;
}

.tabbed.skin-silver {
  border-bottom-color: #bdc3c7;
}

.tabbed.skin-silver ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-silver ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-silver ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #d7dde1;
  color: #666;
}

.tabbed.skin-silver ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-silver ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-silver ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #e3e9ed;
}

.tabbed.skin-silver ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-silver ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-silver ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #bdc3c7;
  color: #fff;
}

.tabbed.skin-asbestos {
  border-bottom-color: #7f8c8d;
}

.tabbed.skin-asbestos ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-asbestos ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-asbestos ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #99a6a7;
}

.tabbed.skin-asbestos ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-asbestos ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-asbestos ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #a5b2b3;
}

.tabbed.skin-asbestos ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-asbestos ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-asbestos ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #7f8c8d;
}

.tabbed.skin-dodgerblue {
  border-bottom-color: dodgerblue;
}

.tabbed.skin-dodgerblue ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-dodgerblue ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-dodgerblue ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

.tabbed.skin-dodgerblue ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-dodgerblue ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-dodgerblue ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #33ccff;
}

.tabbed.skin-dodgerblue ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-dodgerblue ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-dodgerblue ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

.tabbed.skin-gray-black {
  border-bottom-color: #28343b;
}

.tabbed.skin-gray-black,
.tabbed.skin-gray-black ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-gray-black ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-gray-black ul .myradio+label:after {
  transition: none;
}

.tabbed.skin-gray-black ul .myradio+label,
.tabbed.skin-gray-black ul .myradio+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-gray-black ul .myradio+label:after {
  background-color: #68737b;
}

.tabbed.skin-gray-black ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-gray-black ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-gray-black ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #707a83;
}

.tabbed.skin-gray-black ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-gray-black ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-gray-black ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIwJSIgeTI9IjEwMCUiPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI2I1YmRjOCIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEwMCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiMyODM0M2IiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMSIvPgogIDwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+CiAgPHJlY3QgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjEiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
}

.tabbed.skin-black-glass {
  border-bottom-color: #0a0809;
}

.tabbed.skin-black-glass,
.tabbed.skin-black-glass ul li,
.tabbed.skin-black-glass ul li:before,
.tabbed.skin-black-glass ul li:after {
  transition: none;
}

.tabbed.skin-black-glass ul li,
.tabbed.skin-black-glass ul li:before,
.tabbed.skin-black-glass ul li:after {
  background-color: #333;
}

.tabbed.skin-black-glass ul .myradio+label:hover,
.tabbed.skin-black-glass ul .myradio+label:hover:before,
.tabbed.skin-black-glass ul .myradio+label:hover:after {
  background-color: #444;
}

.tabbed.skin-black-glass ul .myradio:checked+label,
.tabbed.skin-black-glass ul .myradio:checked+label:before,
.tabbed.skin-black-glass ul .myradio:checked+label:after {
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIwJSIgeTI9IjEwMCUiPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI2FlYmNiZiIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjUwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzZlNzc3NCIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjUwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzBhMGUwYSIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEwMCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiMwYTA4MDkiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMSIvPgogIDwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+CiAgPHJlY3QgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjEiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
```

```html
<div class="tabbed round">
  <ul>
    <form action="#">
      <input name="myradio" type="radio" id="radio1" class="myradio" checked />
      <label for="radio1">Tab 1</label>
      <input name="myradio" type="radio" id="radio2" class="myradio" />
      <label for="radio2">Tab 2</label>
      <div class='border'></div>
      <section>
        Content for Tab 1
      </section>
      <section>
        Content for Tab 2..!
      </section>
    </form>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You are simply awesome!!! :X I program in java and python but my frontend skill is really low, do you have some sugestions for  some tutorials that i could do so i can level up my frontend skill ? :) Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help! You can watch [Youtube videos](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCW5YeuERMmlnqo4oq8vwUpg/videos) to level-up. Please mark the answer as accepted